# executing table valued valued function in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table valued function with one parameter

mytabfunct(@para nvarchar(20))

this function returns 4 values.

Now I have a table named Employee and I am running a query like this:

```
select
Fname, Lname,
(select
 * from mytabfunct
 ('joseph'))
from  Employee where
Fname='joseph';
```

but it is giving me the error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

I checked for the Error and on some of the forum I found that the error is bcz my function is returning multiple records. But how can I get all those 4 values with the other values like Fname, Lname etc in Employee tbale.

what is wrong here , I am not able to fix.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to edit but it is saying there is some error. give me a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY to execute your function against each row in the table, passing a row's column as the parameter, and joining all the rows from the results in the result.

You didn't give a more concrete example of your query, so I can't give you a clearer example, but this is what you should look for.  use CROSS APPLY just like you would an INNER JOIN, only there's no ON clause.

Okay, from the updated query, yours would look something like this:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, x.ColumnName
  FROM Employees
       CROSS APPLY mytabfunct(Fname) x
```

If you just do a SELECT mytabfunct('Joseph') you'll get a result set with some column names.  You'll need to change "ColumnName" to one of the column names from your table-valued function in the above statement.  You didn't show what the function returns, so I can't get more specific than that.  But try this and see if it gets you closer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
select e.FName
    , e.LName
    , t.Col1
    , t.Col2
    , t.Col3
    , t.Col4
from Employee e
cross apply dbo.mytabfunct(e.FName) t
where e.FName = 'joseph'
```

What concerns me though is your function receives FName as the only parameter. This is an indication that you can only have 1 person with any given name. And of course if your function is more than a single statement it needs to be rethought as multi-statement table valued functions are horrible for a performance standpoint.

Comment: But is it really faster to build a cursor and step each record to call a record specific function or SProc and update the ONE record?